# Help understanding this Circuit

Tags: relay

I have a latching relay that I don't quite understand.  It's pretty simple as far as operation goes.  If you apply power to contact B, (A is common) the relay latches.  If you switch power to contact #8, it resets.  I just don't understand how.  It looks like the diodes will block power to the coil when applied to #8?  and I don't understand why this works to reset the relay...

[image]

Comment: I would agree, could always be a printing error.

Comment: No its not a printing error - check out the datasheet for KL12 (page2) http://www2.schneider-electric.com/resources/sites/SCHNEIDER_ELECTRIC/content/live/FAQS/238000/FA238289/en_US/8501K%20from%208501CT0301%20Catalog%202008.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Whether the relay latches or resets depends on the polarity that you put on the coil. That version was meant to be used with AC, and the terminal that you use, either pin B or pin 8, determines the polarity by way of those diodes.

If you look on page 2 of the datasheet, right below the unit in question is a unit without diodes, meant to be used with DC. Notice it is the polarity of the DC that determines whether the relay latches or resets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am not sure I understand the polarity part of the answer.  This is a 120V AC.  In this the COM always stays COM and you apply 120VAC to one pin or the other.  I understand reversing polarity of a DC circuit, just not with this AC circuit?

Comment: The diodes rectify the applied AC.  If you apply AC to terminal B, the diode will pass positive pulses to the coil.  AC on terminal 8, its diode will pass negative pulses to the coil.